# How to change the font weight and font size of the label in Quasar Tab

Tags: vue.js, sass, tabs, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm using Q-Tab in my project and I tried to change the font-size and font weight of the label of the tab but I can't change it. I tried the typography in  quasar but all of them still didn't work.

```js
<q-tabs
  v-model="tab"
  dense
  class="text-weight-bold"
  active-color="purple"
  indicator-color="purple"
  align="justify"
  narrow-indicator
>
    <q-tab :ripple="false" name="devices" label="Mail"/>
    <q-tab :ripple="false" name="device-data" label="Alarms" />
    <q-tab :ripple="false" name="user-roles" label="Movies" />
</q-tabs>`
```

What should I do to change the font-size and make them all bold?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the `api label of q-tab`.

do this

```
<q-tab>Mail<q-tab>
```

by doing that you can change it's font-weight, font-size, everything in 3 ways.

```
1. by defining class name

class="tab"
```

and style it

```
.tab{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

2. is directly style in q-tab

```
style="font-size:20px; font-weight:normal;"
```

3. is using quasar typography

> class= "text-subtitle2 text-weight-thin"

Answer (score 0):

Add style do this in `app.scss`

```
.q-tab .q-tab__label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```